# How to get response from url windows batch

Tags: command-line, batch, powershell, shell-script

I have a shell script I am converting to windows batch. In the shell script I make a curl request to a URL where I store it's response in a variable, and then I pass that variable as a parameter to a second URL, and make a second curl call and store it's response in another variable final

**Example:**

`initial='curl -s https://some-url/id'`

*Response:* 25

`final='curl -s https://some-url/id/${initial}'`

*Response:* ABC.123.456

How can I do something similar in batch script?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://some-url/id')"
```